# How to use dynamic ListBoxes in php(Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, scripting, listbox

Actually I am developing one website where i want to assign orders to delivery staff and area or bakers from where he will pick up the delivery material. 
[image]

Above picture shows area name and bakers from where delivery staff will pickup the delivery material. So for each order (row) i want to create 2 List Boxes and depending on selection of 1st listbox i want to change the content of 2nd listbox.

```
<select name="<?phpecho $CurrentOrders->comment_ID; ?>" id="courseid" style="width:100%;">
    <option value="">-----Select Pick Up Area----</option>
    <?php
        $Area = DB::table('area')
            ->get();
        foreach ($Area as $Area) {
    ?>
    <option id="<?php echo $Area->area_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $Area->area_name; ?>"><?php $Area->area_name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

</td>
```

Above code is to create dynamically listboxes.

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#1").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
            //alert(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_section.php",
                //data: dataString,
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function (html){
                    $("#sectionid").html(html);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Above script is to create the content of 2nd listboc based on selection of 1st listbox.

```
<?php

if($_POST['id']) {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql=DB::table('vendors')
        ->where('vendors_area','=',$id)
        ->get();
    $count=0;
    foreach($sql as $sql) {
        $count++;
    }
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "<option selected='selected'>---- Select Section Name ----        </option>";
        foreach($sql as $sql) {
            $id=$sql->vendors_id;
            $data=$sql->vendors_name;
            echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And above code is to create and show the content of 2nd listbox based on selection of 1st.

But all this codes are working for only 1 listbox. It is not working dynamically Even if have changed  written scripts for all listboxws as i written for 1st listbox(as #1).
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
$("#1").change(function ()
```

to

```
$(document).on('change',"#1",function()
```

in your javascript code

Comment: What will happen then?

Comment: For dynamic generated elements, it will not trigger any event by using `$("#1").change(function ()`

Comment: So for other element for example for element 2 $(document).on('change',"#2",function() is needed?

Comment: no, change it to `$(document).on('change',"#courseid",function()`